# Determining contour that contains gradient points

Tags: matlab

I have XYZ data and I plotted it with contourf after gridding the data. Then I used the gradient function on the gridded data. With a threshold I isolated gradient values which are above it. Then I plotted them on the same plot; but now, I need to extract contour lines which contains these points, in the way of separating gradient values based on contours.

Here is the plot and code:

```
axes(handles.axes1);
cla(handles.axes1);

threshGradient=.07;
[px,py] = gradient(zC,spX(2)-spX(1),spY(2)-spY(1));
pmag=sqrt((px).^2+(py).^2);
inGrad=pmag>threshGradient;


% contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zC, 12);
contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zC, 200,'LineColor','none');
% contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zC, 200);
colormap(handles.axes1,'jet');
colorbar(handles.axes1);
axis equal
caxis([minmax(zC)]);
hold on
plot(reshape(xC(inGrad),[],1),reshape(yC(inGrad),[],1),'.','Color','r')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what is your desired output? Can you upload some sort of visualization of it?

Comment: It is not very clear what you try to do, nor what the question is